# Passing Value from a custom HTML form into a list.

Tags: custom-form

For my work I am doing a project where I need to create a form that an end user can put data into. This form needs to be a custom form that I make through Visual Studio ASP.net. I can make the form just fine, but what I need to know is how to pass the values that the end user will put into the form into an existing list on my SharePoint site. If anyone has ever done something like this I would greatly appreciate some advice and maybe some example code of how I might do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think of this way, create a visual web part and it just work like asp.net form only.

so from there you can easily update a list where you want to store the data.

you can go for sandboxed solution instead of farm solution.

References : [How To Create Visual WebPart](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1020663/Simple-Steps-to-Create-a-Visual-Web-Part-in-ShareP)

[How to create Visual WebParts-2](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/24/how-to-create-a-custom-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013/)